# How to add citations in a web page?

Tags: jquery-plugins, html, citations

I want to add bibliography citations in a web page. 
What is the easiest way to do this ?

I have found JQuery plugins for creating footnotes, like [this one](http://ignorethecode.net/blog/2010/04/20/footnotes/#fnref:275.footnotes), but they still require to write some boilerplate html code, and the definition of citation entries (e.g., [Einstein 1939.]) is not automatic :(

I am wondering if there is something in the style of bibtex for html pages.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: thanks for the feedback @j08691, I rewrote the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several tools for generating citations and bibliographies in webpages that are based around the [Citation Style Language](http://citationstyles.org/). Which is most useful depends on your platform and desired source of bibliographic metadata. Examples are [KCite](http://wordpress.org/plugins/kcite/) (for WordPress), [Zotpress](http://wordpress.org/plugins/zotpress/) (for WordPress in combination with Zotero), the [Bibliography Module](https://drupal.org/project/biblio) for Drupal, and [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/index.html).